# 403 with axios but 200 with python.requests

Tags: axios, python-requests, authorization, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I have an apigateway that uses IAM as the authorization type. If I use [aws_requests_auth](https://pypi.org/project/aws-requests-auth/) (`python`) I get a 200, but when I use axios I get a 403.

Completely ran out of ideas at this point. I'm rabbit-holing into the python library and translating that to typescript, but it seems like it shouldn't be so difficult.

So far I've tried

> aws4

```js
import { sign } from 'aws4'
import axios, {AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios'


const request = {
  host: '<api-id>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
  url: 'https://<api-id>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<api-resource>',
  method: 'POST',
  data,
  headers: {
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}

const signedRequest = sign(request, {
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  sessionToken: process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
})

axios(signedRequest as AxiosRequestConfig)
  .then(() => {console.log()})
  .catch((error) => {console.log(error)})
```

which returns

```bash
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403
```

> @aws-amplify/core

```js
import { Signer } from '@aws-amplify/core'

const request = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://<api-id>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<api-resource>',
  data
}
const accessInfo = {
  access_key: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secret_key: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  session_token: process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
}

const serviceInfo = {
  service: 'execute-api',
  region: 'us-east-1'
}

const signedRequest = Signer.sign(request, accessInfo, serviceInfo)


axios(signedRequest as AxiosRequestConfig)
  .then(() => {console.log()})
  .catch((error) => {console.log(error)})
```

which returns

```bash
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403
```

> python (this works)

```py
import requests
from aws_requests_auth.boto_utils import BotoAWSRequestsAuth

auth = BotoAWSRequestsAuth(
    aws_host="<api-id>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
    aws_region='us-east-1',
    aws_service="execute-api",
)

response = requests.post(
    "https://<api-id>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<api-resource>",
    auth=auth,
    json=data,
)
print(response)
```

which returns `<Response [200]>`

*Important*

- If I copy the headers from `python`: `response.request.headers` a into axios directly it works. Which makes me think this is a problem with the way I'm using `aws4`, but have no idea what the problem is
- Postman also works

Thanks for your help